# Refreshing Windows Azure VPN tunnel

Tags: azure, vpn

Does anybody know how to "reset" the VPN tunnel of Windows Azure Virtual Network? The networking guys here are asking me to do so. What they mean is to "refresh" the connection. Since I'm not a VPN expert I don't fully understand this request. They told me this is frecuent when configuring VPN tunnels on hardware VPN concentrators (such as Cisco, Juniper, etc).

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Azure Virtual Network, once you configured the VPN connection the connection is available all the time and if by any reason the connection was down, the tunnel should typically be automatically reestablished.

Also once you configure the VPN, the tunnel reestablished within a few seconds. Also sometime the connectivity status may not update on portal immediately as portal update happens in about 5 mins however the VPN may be established underneath. Users are not able to refresh the VPN by portal or using Powershell at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Avkash's response, Azure will attempt to establish a VPN tunnels with your on-premise device periodically, so there is no need for manual steps on your device.

To dive a bit into the internals, the Azure gateway attempts to establish an IPsec tunnel. To create this tunnel, the Azure gateway and your VPN device needs to negotiate a series of security associations. These are called Phase 1 (isakmp) and Phase 2 (ipsec) SAs. These SAs contains mutually agreed upon parameters (security keys, lifetimes, etc) that both device will use to encrypt packets between the two endpoints.

When you say that you want to "reset" your connection, I'm assuming you're looking for steps to  clear and renegotiate these SAs. You can do this from your device's side, by issuing the following commands after logging into your device. This should notify the Azure side and cause renegotiation to occur.

**Cisco ASA & ISR devices**

```
clear crypto isakmp sa
clear crypto ipsec sa
```

**Juniper SSG/ISG devices**

```
clear ike all
```

**Juniper SRX/J devices**

```
clear security ike security-associations
```